# How to add selected in the below code?

Tags: php, mysql, selected

How to add selected in the below code?

```
echo '<select class="w-select selection-produit" id="field" name="Ville">';
echo '<option value="">Choisir une ville...</option>';
$req19="SELECT * FROM ville";
$res19=mysql_query($req19);

while($data4=mysql_fetch_array($res19)){
  echo '<option value="'.$data4['Nom_ville'].'">'.$data4['Nom_ville'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: you just add it. The *operative* word here is `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, just use `selected`. E.g. the following code checks if the town is `Mulhouse` (où est le musée du chemin de fer...) and if so selects this entry.

```
echo '<select class="w-select selection-produit" id="field" name="Ville">';
echo '<option value="">Choisir une ville...</option>';
$req19="SELECT * FROM ville";
$res19=mysql_query($req19);
while($data4=mysql_fetch_array($res19)) {
    // check if the town is equal to Mulhouse
    // equal to if (this) else (that)
    $sel = ($data4['Nom_ville'] == 'Mulhouse')?"selected":"";
    echo "<option value='".$data4['Nom_ville']."' $sel>".$data4['Nom_ville']."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: When I click the Search button is missing

Answer (score -1):

```
$valueWantSelect="the value you want selected";
$define = "";
echo '<select class="w-select selection-produit" id="field"      name="Ville">';
echo '<option value="">Choisir une ville...</option>';
$req19="SELECT * FROM ville";
$res19=mysql_query($req19);

while($data4=mysql_fetch_array($res19))
```

{

```
$define = ($data4['Nom_ville'] == $valueWantSelect) ?  "selected='selected'" : "";

echo '<option value="'.$data4['Nom_ville'].'"  '.$define.'>'.$data4['Nom_ville'].'</option>';

$define="";
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: It is better to add some description or commentary to your answer describing how your answer works to solve the problem in the question. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO.

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila Indeed. Even more so, if the given answer has some serious formatting issues...

Comment: Thank you very much for solution ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try like this hope it will work for you

```
foreach ($request as $data) {

                    if ($data->cat_id == $catee) {
                        echo "<option  selected = 'selected' value='" . $data->cat_id . "'>" . $data->cat_name . "</option>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value='" . $data->cat_id . "'>" . $data->cat_name . "</option>";
                    }
                }
```